# How to use the elements of an array on another function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to make a game for my programming class and part of it envolves shuffling some cards (represented by numbers) and then showing them on another function.

Since the cards are then distributed into two arrays I need to access those values on the show function.

```
int deck_shuffle()
{
    int deck[] {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10};
        srand(time(0));


random_shuffle(&deck[0], &deck[28]);
        int player1_hand[] {deck[0], deck[1], deck[2]};
        int player2_hand[] {deck[3], deck[4], deck[5]}
}



void show_cards()
{
cout <<"PLAYER 1 HAND" << endl ;


cout<< player1_hand[0] <<  endl ;
cout<< player1_hand[1] << endl;
cout<< player1_hand[2] << endl;

cout <<"PLAYER 2 HAND" << endl ;

cout<< player2_hand[0] << endl;
cout<< player2_hand[1] << endl;
cout<< player2_hand[2] << endl;


}
```

How can I use the values of the arrays

```
int player1_hand[]
```

and

```
int player2_hand[]
```

On the function:

```
void show_cards()
```

??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, next time please indicate which programming language you are using, so people who know this language will easily see this question.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `=` sign when declaring arrays. This code won't compile.

Comment: Is there any problem passing an array as a parameter to void show_card()

Comment: For basic assignments like this, its very common to just make your variables global by creating them _outside_ of a function, normally in your cpp file before main() or any other function is written.  Global variables will be accessible from all functions without the need to pass parameters.  Once you getting working with globals, you can then play with passing things around as parameters.

Comment: @ForceBru, that's a new C++11 syntax that does compile.  It can also be used with classes and STL containers. More info [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)...